# How to Prove $V\otimes sl(k)=sl(V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

Let V be a vector space over a field $k$. Let $sl(n)$ be the set of all matrices elements from $k$ with trace zero.

Is it true that $V\otimes _k sl(n)=sl(V)= \text{set of all $n\times$ n matrices elements from $V$ with trace zero }$

Has edited the question itself from $M_n(V)\otimes sl(k)=sl(V)$ to $V\otimes sl(k)=sl(V)$.

Comment: What does it mean for a matrix with elements of $V$ to have trace zero? In any case, the dimensions seem wrong.

Comment: Is $V$ an algebra on top of being a vector space?  If not, then can we multiply two elements of $M_n(V)$, or do we just have $V^{n^2}$?

Comment: Perhaps you really want $gl(V)$, rather than $M_n(V)$.

Comment: @levap: you can add elements of V; so trace zero makes sense, right?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I am not really sure about the correct statement. So I don't know whether $Gl(V)$ will make the statement correct. By the way, by $gl(V)$, do you mean $GL(V)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Why do we need to multiply to elements of $M_n(V)$?

Comment: The entire point of matrices, I think, is that they denote linear maps, and that multiplying matrices corresponds to a composition of maps.  If you can only add two matrices, then they're nothing more than a vector space.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean that $\mathrm{sl}_n(k) \otimes_k V \approx \mathrm{sl}_n(V)$. The isomorphism is induced by the bilinear map $\mathrm{sl}_n(k) \times V \rightarrow \mathrm{sl}_n(V)$ sending a pair $(A,v)$ where $A = (a_{ij})$ is an $n \times n$ traceless scalar matrix and $v \in V$ is a vector to the vector-valued matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} v & \dots & a_{1n} v \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} v & \dots & a_{nn} v \end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{sl}_n(V). $$

Comment: I think you are right, I meant exactly the same what you wrote. Thank you.